# How to install the JSystem plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

As per the JSystem documentation it's stated that the installer of JSystem has a little checkbox which install the eclipse plugin, but the screenshot on the manual it's for Windows XP(http://www.jsystemtest.org/sites/default/files/help/Chapter%203%20Getting%20Started%20with.htm#_Toc206753837) and right now I'm using ubuntu 12.04 with Eclipse Juno. I just installed JSystem here and can't find that little checkbox.

Also the documentation is sparse and short. Does anybody know how to install the JSystem plugin for Eclipse?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the Eclipse plugin is no longer part of the JSystem installation. 
If you still want to use it, you can grab one of the older installation packages from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsystemtest/files/?source=navbar)

(Version 5.7.02 would do the trick).

If are having problems with the Linux installation, you can install it on windows and copy manually the **com.ignis.eclipse.plugin_5.7.02** jar from the *jsystem/runner/Eclipse* folder to the Eclipse plugins folder.

After restarting the Eclipse, you would be able to create a new JSystem project using the plugin.

One of the main reasons that the plugin is no longer provided and supported is that JSystem is now using Maven and most of the plugin functionality is now done via Maven archetypes.

To learn more about it please refer to the [Getting started guide](http://jsystem.org/quick-start-guide/)